# Using an array with data to make elements using an iterative #each with a template

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have this 'post' template:

```
<section class="posts">
<div class="post" data-price="{{price}}" data-city="{{city}}" data-condition="{{condition}}">
  <div class="post-contents">
    <div class="post-image-container">
      <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="post-info-container">
      <a href="#" class="post-title">{{name}}</a> <span class="post-price">${{price}}</span> <span class="post-city">({{city}})</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

And an array of data in 'postData.json' that looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "price": 500,
    "city": "Eugene",
    "condition": "poor",
    "photoURL": "(big url)",
    "description": "Super nice laptop"
  }]
```

I am attempting to get the data from this array into templates and into my body, but I am not sure how to iterate over it and transfer that data into the template and into my body, but here is what I have:

```
<section id="posts">
    {{#each postData}}
      {{> post}}
      {{
          name: allPosts.description;
          city: allPosts.city
          url: allPosts.photoURL
          condition: allPosts.conditions
          price: allPosts.price]
      }}
    {{/each}}
  </section>
```

Let me know any questions, just really stuck and can't quite figure it out. Thank you for any help, everything helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over your data you need to feed the current data-set to your partial by updating your code to look like this `{{> post this}}`. Right now your partial is not being passed any data.

[Handlesbars Partials documentation.](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#dynamic-partials)